# How to include two observed time series in state space model

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm working with the "State space modeling: Local Linear Trends" example (https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_local_linear_trend.html).  I'm trying to modify the code to work with two observed time series (i.e., two observation equations).

I've modified the design matrix (in the **init** method) and the 'obs_cov' (in the update method) to account for two observed time series, but the results only estimate a single epsilon.

```
class LocalLinearTrend(sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel):
    def __init__(self, endog):
        .
        .
        .
        # Initialize the matrices
        self.ssm['design'] = np.array([[1, 0],
                                  [1, 0]])      # <--- added this
        .
        .
        .


    def update(self, params, *args, **kwargs):
        .
        .
        .
        self.ssm['obs_cov', 0, 0] = params[0]
        self.ssm['obs_cov', 1, 1] = params[0]      # <--- added this
        .
        .
        .
```

I expect the result variance parameters (in the variable "params") to include 4 elements (one epsilon for each observation equation and the chi and zeta values corresponding to the two state variables), but it only includes 3 elements (chi, zeta, and a single epsilon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. The issue here is that `params` is an array of parameters, and `params[0]` refers to the first parameter. For that reason, the lines:

```
self.ssm['obs_cov', 0, 0] = params[0]
self.ssm['obs_cov', 1, 1] = params[0]
```

set both diagonal elements of the observation covariance matrix to the same value.

You want to add a new parameter, which you do by adding a new parameter to the `param_names` and `start_params` properties. For example, you want something like:

```
@property
def param_names(self):
    return ['sigma2.measurement.v1', 'sigma2.measurement.v2', 'sigma2.level', 'sigma2.trend']

@property
def start_params(self):
    std = np.std(self.endog, axis=0)
    return np.r_[std, 1., 1.]
```

Then, in your `update` method, you would want something like:

```
def update(self, params, **kwargs):
    params = super(LocalLinearTrend, self).update(params, **kwargs)

    # Observation covariance
    self.ssm['obs_cov',0,0] = params[0]
    self.ssm['obs_cov',1,1] = params[1]

    # State covariance
    self.ssm[self._state_cov_idx] = params[2:]
```

(Note: when adding new parameters, you generally also want to adjust `transform_params` and `untransform_params` to enforce any restrictions on the parameter space. However, the versions of these functions in the example `LocalLinearTrend` class that you linked to will continue to work for the new parameter vector defined as above, so in this case you don't need to do anything there).